# How to add a workspace in blender for a small monitor?

Tags: workspaces

I want to add a new workspace in Blender however my monitor is too small and the plus button doesn't fit in the screen. How do I add a new workspace?[image]

Comment: u can pan that area by holding down ur mouse wheel button and dragging to your left just like when u rotate around a 3D object.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mouse wheel, scrolling will enable you to slide that header bar around.

If you don't have a mouse wheel then the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown/PgUp</kbd> cycles through workspaces.

Comment: You can also drag the header bar left and right with the mousewheel held down.